# How to integrate Chatbot in Skype for business On Premises using C# in Microsoft Bot Framwork

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot, skype-for-business

I have created a Bot using Microsoft Bot framework and i want to integrate it with Skype for Business On Premises.How i can integrate it.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating bots with Skype for Business is still in preview, and can be learned about [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview) There is a note in there, addressing using Skype for Business on-premises:

> For the Skype for Business hybrid environment, the New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint cmdlet will output an additional on-premises cmdlet to be run in your Skype for Business Server (on-premises) Management Shell. For more information about bot setup for the Skype for Business hybrid environment, see Skype for Business Bot - Hybrid environment support.
>
> Also, see Skype for Business Bot - Common Errors to troubleshoot some of the common bot setup issues.

So while this is currently theoretically possible, bear in mind that it's still (as of 31 Oct 2018) in PREVIEW.